# Snowflake scripting error in anonymous block execution

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Getting below error:

> Error:'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 8 at position 6 : SQL compilation
> error: error line 1 at position 40 (line 130) invalid identifier
> 'ROW_VARIABLE.ID' (line 130)

code:

```sql
DECLARE
    id_variable INTEGER;
    price_variable float;
    c1 cursor for select id from invoices;
BEGIN
    Open c1;
    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
      SELECT id, price INTO :id_variable, :price_variable 
          FROM invoices where id=row_variable.id; 
    END FOR;
    Close c1;
            
    RETURN id_variable || ' ' || price_variable;
END;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this block? What are you trying to achieve? Even if the SELECT would work you would only return the value from the last SELECT since the other ones are lost, unless your cursor has only 1 row in it. Why not returning directly a table like `RETURN TABLE(RESULTSET_FROM_CURSOR(c1));`?

Answer (score 0):

The bridge between Snowflake Scripting and "normal SQL" fails sometimes, so in semi complex SQL, the use of the looping record confuses the SQL compiler.

to get around this put the `row_variable.id` into a local varaible, which you can access via the `:<token>` syntax, like so:

```
DECLARE
    row_id INTEGER;
    id_variable INTEGER;
    price_variable float;
    c1 cursor for select id from invoices;
BEGIN
    Open c1;
    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
      row_id := row_variable.id;
      SELECT id, price INTO :id_variable, :price_variable 
          FROM invoices where id = :row_id; 
    END FOR;
    Close c1;
            
    RETURN id_variable || ' ' || price_variable;
END;
```

thus with the content of invoices being:

```
create table invoices(id int, price float);
insert into invoices values (10, 12.345);
```

we get:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| 10 12.345 |

To Sergiu's point, if we add a second row:

```
insert into invoices values (11, 13.456);
```

this block will only return the last row,

Also of note, I very much hope the SQL as it stands is not what you plan to do, as you are select all rows from a table, and then finding the matches. I assume you are going to do "something else" and this is just a tiny demo code. But even then unless you are doing super complex work, you should try use a join or some other method, to avoid "per row" operations on the result of the first table.

Comment: Yes if access variable as :row_variable.id it is working, Thank you